# How could we validate all possible combinations of input parameters?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

Say, I am writing unit tests for two functions declared as below:

```
void target_func_1(int param1, int param2);
void target_func_2(int param1, int param2, int param3, int param4, int param5, int param6);
```

For two above functions, all input parameters are expected to be either -1 or positive.

All possible test cases for validating input parameters of `target_func_1` are listed below

- param1 < -1 && param2 >= -1 // failed
- param1 >= -1 && param2 < -1 // failed
- param1 < -1 && param2 < -1 // failed
- param1 >= -1 && param2 >= -1 // succeeded

This looks simple. But, what about `target_func_2`? There can be extreme number of possible combinations of six input parameters. Do I have to write all those test cases for `target_func_2`?

Comment: There are sure others. But I recently gave a presentation on tdd, and I realized that I do **not** have a answer badge for the TDD tag here. Thus I added this tag to my list of tags; and yes, I am coming by on a regular base ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is: you do not write a method that takes 6 parameters.

In other words: when you read about *clean code* (for example by studying the excellent book with that name by Robert Martin and others) you will find that such a high number of parameters is absolutely *discouraged*.

And please understand: this is not only because you have so many permutations to **test** - but beyond that: these parameters are probably all **used** within your production code.

In that sense, the real answer is not about how to reasonable test such methods. It is: you can't test such methods in a reasonable way; you can't implement them in a reasonable way thus you shouldn't write them.

( please note: this is about methods that have to make decisions based on the parameters; if you say, just print them for example it would be a somewhat different story )

As on *how many*, let's quote the aforementioned book:

> The ideal number of arguments for a function is zero (niladic). Next comes one (monadic), followed closely by two (dyadic). Three arguments (triadic) should be avoided where possible. More than three (polyadic) requires very special justification—and then shouldn’t be used anyway.

And please note: this is *independent* of the underlying programming language!

For legacy code, I recommend a *two folded* approach. First you focus on the **public contract** of that method. Meaning: you try to understand "what goes in" and "what goes out". Then you might do some coverage measurements, and maybe add more tests (tailored to take certain paths within that method). But for the record: you write tests to enable you to *refactor* those such legacy code.

Beyond that: another approach *might* be to look into tests based on the *[QuickCheck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck)* idea. Meaning: you specify *properties* of your method, and then the framework creates *random* parameters for you and tries to find situations that lead failures (regarding these properties).

Comment: Then can you please tell me, for C++, how many parameters would be maximum for a function? And, what about legacy code?

Comment: And I added another paragraph. Not sure if quickcheck is the right tool there, but tehre should definitely be a c++ implementation for it!